# Using command line to send email with subject

Tags: bash, selenium

I have looked at the other answers on SO and Google, but none of them are working for me.  I need to send the results of a Selenium test to my email, but I cannot get the email to send with a subject.  Everything else I need it to do works.  I have this:

```
php codecept.phar run acceptance -vv Path/MyTest.php 2>&1 | tee -a log-file.log | sendmail myEmail@email.com
```

I cannot use mail for this, it must be sendmail.  Does anyone know how to add the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{ echo Subject:subject; echo test; } | sendmail email@xx.com
```

something like this should work:

```
{ echo Subject:subject ; php codecept.phar run acceptance -vv Path/MyTest.php 2>&1 | tee -a log-file.log; } | sendmail myEmail@email.com
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked like a charm.   I didn't realize 
    { echo Subject:subject ; 
had to be in the beginning.